# Chunking array within array algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

first question on stackoverflow, i'm struggling with this algorithm. This is supposed to slice my array in 5 like "[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8]]" but all i got is "[ [ 0, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 6, 7, 8 ] ]"

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [];
  console.log(Math.floor(arr.length / size));
  for (i = 0; i <= (Math.floor(arr.length / size)) + 1; ++i) {
    var cut = size;
    newArr.push(arr.splice(0, cut));
  }
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    newArr.push(arr.splice(0, size + (arr.length - size)));
  }
  return newArr;
}
chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2);
// expected - [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8]]
```

If you have any tips about the way of asking questions, i'd be happy to receive any advice !

Comment: Welcome to **stackoverflow** !. This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask get started on how to as a question here on stackoverflow.

Comment: your algorithm is not working because of this line: `for (i = 0; i <= (Math.floor(arr.length / size)) + 1; ++i) {...}` witch is `for (i = 0; i <= (Math.floor(9 / 2)) + 1; ++i) {...}`, initially `Math.floor(arr.length / size)` is equal 5 but after each execution you shrink your `arr.length` by `size` so now you have `for (i = 1; i <= (Math.floor(7 / 2)) + 1; ++i) {...}` then `for (i = 2; i <= (Math.floor(5 / 2)) + 1; ++i) {...}` and `for (i = 3; i <= (Math.floor(3 / 2)) + 1; ++i) {...}` is not going to execute. So you do only 3 executions instead of 5. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @brigysl Yes thank you ! I forgot this one.. splice is dangerous !

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple `for` loop with `Array#slice`, because slice doesn't change the length of the original array:

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var chunked = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) { // increment i by the size
    chunked.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
  }
  
  return chunked;
}

var result = chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I thought the last .slice() must perfectly fit the array index, in this case (0, 1) :o

It worked perfectly, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Since you are removing element using [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the array length get decreased so instead of calculating the range cache the range for the `for` loop condition. Although use [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) and avoid the unnecessary if statement.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [],
    range = Math.ceil(arr.length / size);

  for (i = 0; i < range; i++) {
    newArr.push(arr.splice(0, size));
  }

  return newArr;
}
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2));
```

Comment: Care to explain to OP why?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
     newArr = [];
     for (i=0,j=arr.length; i<j; i+=size) {
        newArr.push(arr.slice(i,i+size));
     }
    return newArr;
}
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2));
// expected - [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    return arr.reduce(function (accum, elem) {
        var curr = accum[accum.length - 1];
        if (curr.length < size) curr.push(elem); else accum.push([elem]);
        return accum;
    }, [[]]);
}

var result = chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2);
console.log( JSON.stringify(result) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Here is how I would do that. Let me know if you have any questions about this approach.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [];
  while(arr.length > 0){
    newArr.push(arr.splice(0, size)); 
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop and splice the length of the wanted size for a grouped array.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(array, size) {
    var result = [];
    while (array.length) {
        result.push(array.splice(0, size));
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Functionally you can do as follows;

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(a,g){
  return Array(Math.ceil(a.length/g)).fill()
                                     .map((_,i) => [a[g*i]].concat(a.slice(g*i+1, g*i+g)));
}

var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
 result = [];

result = chunkArrayInGroups(arr,2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

result = chunkArrayInGroups(arr,3);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

result = chunkArrayInGroups(arr,4);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```